# Underlying provider failed on Open - clueless

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework-6

I know this question seems like a duplicate of numerous other questions, but I have done my research for the past few hours and found *nothing* that solved my problem.

Since I am using Entity Framework 6, everything has worked fine. The first few tests passed flawlessly. However, now that we are running it on the bigger part of the database, this exception pops up after a solid amount of querys.

> The underlying provider failed on Open

at

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

which is called by

> System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

I have narrowed it down and tried to specifically search all around SO, MSDN, CodeProject, and numerous others more for solutions. Obviously, none of them worked. Else I wouldn't be posting this question.

First, some information that might be of use:

- We are using MariaDB 5.5.38, having HeidiSQL as database interface.
- We are using Entity Framework 6.
- We are using an external server to run the program which writes alot of data to a local database. In other words, the server contains the database and the program, and so the database is populated with only local connections.

Now the weird thing comes;

My application runs perfectly for a certain amount of records (about 50.000 records are inserted), and then this error comes up. I caught the exception and tried to let my program continue, which results in the same error being thrown (not that big of a surprise, but worth noting). **However**, if I delete all the records currently in the database, **the program continues**. Therefore we can at least conclude that my data or code is probably not the problem.

My first thought was that perhaps my memory was full - but this wasn't the case (I have at least 18GB left).

My second thought was, that *maybe* the connection pool was too populated. Even though this should not happen because I use the same connection string every time, it could be a flaw in my coding. However, the program does not continue after calling `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools()`, nor does it matter if I add `MaximumPoolSize = 32767` to my connection string.

My third thought was that maybe the `buffer_pool_size` of MariaDB was too small. Again, no luck after increasing it. After researching upon this bufferpool, I found out that it didn't have alot to do with the problem either - but just to make clear that I've looked into it.

I will provide some code which might be causing the problem;

```
string _conStr;

MySqlConnectionStringBuilder providerConnStrBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
providerConnStrBuilder.AllowUserVariables = true;
providerConnStrBuilder.AllowZeroDateTime = true;
providerConnStrBuilder.ConvertZeroDateTime = true;
providerConnStrBuilder.MaximumPoolSize = 32767;
providerConnStrBuilder.Pooling = true;
providerConnStrBuilder.Database = settings["dbname"];
providerConnStrBuilder.Password = = settings["dbpw"];
providerConnStrBuilder.Server = settings["dbsource"];
providerConnStrBuilder.UserID = settings["dbuid"];

EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityConnStrBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entityConnStrBuilder.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
entityConnStrBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerConnStrBuilder.ToString();
entityConnStrBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/MyDbContext.csdl|res://*/MyDbContext.ssdl|res://*/MyDbContext.msl";

_conStr = entityConnStrBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

And for the querys;

```
public void AnyQuery()
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext(_conStr))
    {
        //Doing things with the context.
    }
}
```

And, for those interested, my implementation of `MyDbContext`;

```
public MyDbContext(string conStr) : base(conStr){}
```

Note that I have wrapped every single usage of `MyDbContext` in a `using` statement.

**Summary**: Program runs well, but stops after a certain amount of records inserted. It continues if the database is cleared.

Comment: Can this actually be a timeout issue? A default timeout is set for a transaction. If all the queries are executed in the same transaction, it may be possible that the timeout limit is reached, which can throw such an exception.

Comment: The process goes quite simple; get a record, process it, upload it to the database. The last two are done within the `using` part, therefore the connection is closed afterwards. This works for 49537 records (exactly) and then this error comes up. I doubt it is a timeout, since I cannot see the application "waiting" for a connection (and yes, I have been staring at my screen for about the whole processing time)

Comment: So all of the queries are processed and uploaded within the `using` part? If so, it's either a timeout issue, the connection can not be kept open for the whole time in which the queries need to be processed, or there's something wrong with your 49538th entry. Try constructing the query manually with the data from that entry and letting it run on the database. Chances are it will crash and you will find out what the problem is.

Comment: If there is something wrong with the 49538th query or with the connection, how do you explain the program continueing if I empty the database? I do not think that is the problem. It really points to a memory problem, I just can't find out what it is.

Comment: Well, that is quite interesting. Can there be a database storage limitation, allowing it to only increase to a maximum of x MB?

Comment: You'd say there would be, but I can't seem to find it... kinda stuck here.

Comment: One more suggestion came to mind. Try running *only* the first 49537 queries from within the code, then run the 49538th manually, from within the database UI. This will most likely crash and show you what the actual problem is. Worst case it will at least give you a more accurate message than "The underlying provider failed on Open"